# Include html code in modal from bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

For school, I have to make my own website that shows some basic things to first years. So I got the idea, that I make a modal with Bootstrap. If you press the card, the modal will pop up.

Now, I want in the middle where 'CODE WHERE' is, to show the code for something. For example: let me just print 
 or . But it won't let me, it will convert into HTML all the time and I don't want to convert it. I've looked a lot of pages, but I don't seem to find how. Anyone a solution?
Thank you very much.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div style="cursor: pointer;" class="col-md-12" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
      <div class="card-body">
       Text
      </div>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Code</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
 <pre>
  <code>
    CODE HERE??
  </code>
</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close Modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First way is replacing `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;` inside Your `<code></code>`.

Second way is make it change automatically in javascript:

```
var codeTags = document.querySelectorAll('code');
for (var i = 0; i < codeTags.length; i++) {
    codeTags[i].innerText = codeTags[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Or easier in jQuery:

```
$('code').each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).html());
});
```